# SQL and WordPress: Extract two custom fields with SQL

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

WordPress `wp_postmeta` table is constructed as a key/value pair:

```
ID | meta_key | meta_value
```

I need to get the values of two meta_keys within the result set:

`property_lat` and `property_long`

I will then use these values to assess the radius of a given point.

Answer (score 1):

Two values in one result set:

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE meta_key IN ('property_lat', 'property_long')
```

Two values in one row:

```
SELECT (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='property_lat' LIMIT 1) AS lat, 
       (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='property_long' LIMIT 1) AS lng
```

Comment: Close! But I need both the `property_lat` and `property_long` to be within the same row.

Comment: "#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Comment: Apparently you have multiple rows with the same meta_key. Therefore you can't rely on it. Technically you can utilize LIMIT 1 to avoid this error. But i guess you need to use ID to target specific rows in WHERE clause in subqueries

Answer (score 0):

Preterm's solution can never get you all lat/longitude pairs at once. It can only get you the pair for one ID at a time. I'm not expert enough in SQL to guarantee that this will work right away, but I think you're looking for something like this:

```
SELECT tbl.ID, lat.meta_value, lng.meta_value
FROM wp_postmeta AS tbl
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS lat ON lat.ID = tbl.ID AND lat.meta_key='property_lat'
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS lng ON lng.ID = tbl.ID AND lng.meta_key='property_long'
WHERE meta_key IN ('property_lat', 'property_long')
GROUP BY tbl.ID
```

Comment: I've modified the query, and it seems to work ... `SELECT tbl.ID, lat.meta_value, lng.meta_value
FROM wp_posts AS tbl
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS lat ON lat.post_id = tbl.ID
AND lat.meta_key =  'property_lat'
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS lng ON lng.post_id = tbl.ID
AND lng.meta_key =  'property_long'
LIMIT 0 , 30`However, how might I modify this so that I can get the results by radius? This white paper contains the SQL: http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL

Comment: I would just do that in PHP since I'm better at that. But you seem to already have solved this with SQL, it's even more efficient I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

With your help, I was able to construct my query:

```
SET @centerLat = '48.428289';
SET @centerLng = '-123.380585';

SELECT wp_posts.*,
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( @centerLat ) ) * cos( radians( lat.meta_value ) ) * cos( radians( lng.meta_value ) - radians(@centerLng) ) + sin( radians( @centerLat ) ) * sin( radians( lat.meta_value ) ) ) ) AS distance

FROM wp_posts

LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS lat 
    ON lat.post_id = wp_posts.ID 
        AND lat.meta_key = 'property_lat'

LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS lng 
    ON lng.post_id = wp_posts.ID 
        AND lng.meta_key = 'property_long'

WHERE lat.meta_key IS NOT NULL

HAVING distance > 5

LIMIT 0 , 20
```

Thank you!